# Identify duplicate records and update them with the ID of first occurrence

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicate-data

I have a table like this.

```
ID  Name      Source ID
1   Orange       0
2   Pear         0
3   Apple        0
4   Orange       0
5   Apple        0
6   Banana       0
7   Orange       0
```

What I want to do is:

- For the records with FIRST occurrence of "Name", I want to update the "Source Id" with the "Id" value
- For the records with SECOND and CONSECUTIVE occurrences of "Name", I want to update the "Source Id" with the "Id" value of the FIRST occurrence

So, the table should be updated as follows:

```
ID  Name      Source ID
1   Orange       1
2   Pear         2
3   Apple        3
4   Orange       1
5   Apple        3
6   Banana       6
7   Orange       1
```

How can I do it in SQL (Oracle to be in particular, but I'm fine with General SQL as well) ...

Thanks!

Comment: That's nice. And what have you tried so far?

Comment: What version of Oracle?  Analytic support starts in 9i.  And what have you tried to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should get you what you want:

```
update table a
set source_id = (
    select min(id)
    from table b
    where b.name = a.name
);
```

Comment: Does Oracle support aliases on UPDATE <Table> alias?

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET SourceID = Sub.ID
FROM MyTable 
INNER JOIN (SELECT MIN(ID) as ID, Name FROM MyTable GROUP BY Name) Sub
    ON Sub.Name = MyTable.Name
```

Just use a subquery that lists the min id per name.

Answer (score 1):

Since `ID` is growing autoincrement value (right?) FirstID could be calculated as `MIN(ID)`:

```
UPDATE fruits
  SET SourceID = ag.ID
FROM fruits f 
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT MIN(ID) as ID, Name FROM @fruits
  GROUP BY Name
) ag 
ON ag.Name = f.Name
```